# Windows 10 BSOD after using Update Troubleshooter

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bsod

After the nth failed update to my Windows 10 Professional installation - forcing me to restart my laptop twice for the attempt to install and the rollback - I got fed up with it, and decided to look into a complete reset of the updates. After all, I have hidden lots of updates after failed attempts, and this will logically result in entropy (which Windows has enough of as it is).

So **I ran the Windows Update Troubleshooter, 'fixed' a found error, and now starting my laptop, even in Safe Mode, results in a Blue Screen of Death, with error code ' 0xc000021a'**.

[image: crappy image of BSOD error code: "0xc000021a"]

According to the help center my laptop boots into after a failed start, I don't have any System Restore Points, and the only other viable options seem to be

1). a complete reinstallation, which will let me lose all installed programs, and 
 2). use third-party software to target the (presumably) corrupted files, but I have no idea what software would be appropriate.

**Does anyone know a method to get past this problem without forcing me to go through a complete reinstall of all software?**

Or, more specifically and specialistically, does anyone know how to fix the files the Troubleshooter in all probability has changed?

Can anyone suggest the appropriate software for a USB recovery tool?

Comment: It would be best to analyze the windows dump file created when it blue screened, this will determine the cause of the bsod.

Comment: @Moab - Which requires a working Windows installation.  Which might not be possible.

Comment: It can be harvested and analyzed on another pc.